# Force y-axis scrollbar in textarea element

Tags: css, firefox

http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/LHy9H/

```
<textarea>fofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofooo</textarea>

textarea { width: 500px; line-height: 32px; overflow: auto; height:32px; }
```

I cannot figure out how to force a y-axis scrollbar on the text area in Firefox.
It works fine with Chrome.

In Firefox, the scrollbar doesn't appear until it is a certain height.

Comment: You want to see the scrollbar even when the text is not long enough to be scrollable?

Comment: It is scrollable. it wraps too lines. Compare firefox with chrome and you will see chrome shows a scrollbar, firefox does not until the thing is at least 75px high.

Comment: I made the textarea smaller and now it's scrollable for me. It's scrollable on both Chrome and Firefox for me (I'm on a Mac, dunno if that might change something). The problem that I see (which might be your problem) is that Firefox doesn't show the scrollbar with a size that small, though it is scrollable if you use your mousewheel/trackpad.

Comment: Perhaps Firefox has some built in setting to only show a scrollbar when the size is greater than or equal to 75px?

Answer (score 2):

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

I believe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Does not produce a scrollbar...it shows what LOOKS like a scrollbar...but it is not scrollable until you adjust the height to make it a few lines high.